# Get last record by date for multiple table with many-to-one relationship

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, orm

I have 3 tables :

```
class Item(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    image = models.URLField()

class Prix_x1(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name

    prix = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    saved_at = models.DateTimeField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Prix_x10(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name

    prix = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    saved_at = models.DateTimeField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What i want is to retrive the last price by 1 and by 10 for each Item in my BDD.

I have already tried many things, but either it's not gives me what i want or either the request is like 20seconds

I want to show the result in a table like :

[image: results table]

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with subqueries:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Item.objects.annotate(
    prix_x1=Subquery(
        Prix_x1.objects.filter(
            item=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('prix').order_by('-saved_at')[:1]
    ),
    prix_x10=Subquery(
        Prix_x10.objects.filter(
            item=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('prix').order_by('-saved_at')[:1]
    )
)
```

The `Item`s that arise from this queryset will have two extra attribute `.prix_x1` and `.prix_x10` that contain the `prix` for the last `Prix_x1` and `Prix_x10` records related to that item.

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted, thank a lot !
I just had to change the name of the Subdquery beacause i was dealing with "ValueError: The annotation 'prix_x1' conflicts with a field on the model."